# Get Items with "Web" Class

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services

with di query I can get the specified list object from the collection the property "Items" froom the SPListCollection class.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://sp2010dev/sites/Reply"))

            {

                NetworkCredential Cred = new NetworkCredential("administrator",    "Password.123", "virtualsp.dev");
                context.Credentials = Cred;
                var web = context.Web;

                context.Load(web);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
              try{ 
using (SPSite scSite = new SPSite(fullsite))
                {
                    using (SPWeb webRoot = scSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
SPListItem itemSelezionato = (from SPListItem item in      webRoot.Lists["ContentIndex"].Items
```

has anybody know how could get the same thing using the class "Web" rather than SPWeb ? 
With this class I don't have the "Items" property.

Comment: Can you provide fullname of Web class?

Comment: You code is incomplete. It cuts off after this line: SPListItem itemSelezionato = (from SPListItem item in      webRoot.Lists["ContentIndex"].Items

Answer (score 3):

You are dealing with the Client Object Model.

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("sp2010dev/sites/Reply";))
{ 
     NetworkCredential Cred = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "Password.123","virtualsp.dev");
     context.Credentials = Cred;
     var web = context.Web;
     var listItems = web.Lists["ContentIndex"].Items;
     context.load(listItems);
     context.ExecuteQuery();

     foreach(ListItem item in listItems)
     {
         //Do something with item
     }
}
```

Comment: I  nave not the .Items property using the Web Class.

Comment: Hi, can you post more details about your question please. I am not able to get you sorry.

Comment: I posted all the code above. I got a error when I try to post the "where" condition into the LINQ query.

Comment: Bruno, it seems to me in your code you are mixing the client object model and the server object model...

Comment: True. @BrunoFerreira use **only** the code in my answer above.